# How to restrict user to upload files more than the number specified

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am building a website using asp.net where students upload their assignment files. Short intro to my work is when teacher is creating assignment she specifies(for that assignment only) that how many times a student can upload assignment file of that topic. Problem is i am unable to understand that how i count student has uploaded file how much times?

```
Assignment Table:
Fields: assign_ID, Total_Marks,Title,No_of_Subm

Counter Table:
Fields: Counter_ID,Assig_ID,Std_ID,Counter
```

first one is my assignment table where assignment related data is saving when teacher is creating assignment.. second one is counter table which i have made to keep record of how many times student has upload files.. In counter table counter filed is used for, whenever student uploads file "1" is inserted so that next time it can be counted and matched to No_of_subm that teacher allowed.

Because the database initially has no records in it, I am getting this error:

> > "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"

I am stuck in it please help me out.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciable..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value is not null before set it to a variable.

Eg:

```
if(!reader["Counter"] == DBNull.Value){
       Counter = Convert.toInt32(reader["Counter"]);
  }
```